send queue data with custom expiration in python
Currently I'm trying to send data to a azure queue in storage. I am able to send data but I am unable to custom the expiration time like to 10 seconds 1 day like that. But in azure portal able to do it.
below image azure portal

below is the code
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient, QueueMessage
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time


# Replace with your actual Azure Storage account details
account_name = 'you_account_name'
account_key = 'your_account_key'

connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"


def send_message_to_queue(queue_name, message, ttl_seconds):
    # Instantiate a QueueClient
    queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, queue_name)

    
    # Send message to queue auto expirey in 5 secs
    queue_client.send_message(queue_message, time_to_live = ttl_seconds)
    print(f"Message '{message}' sent to queue '{queue_name}' with expiration in {ttl_seconds} seconds.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue_name = 'your_queue_name'
    message = "hello"
    ttl_seconds = 5  # TTL of 5 seconds
    
    for coordinate in coordinates:
        send_message_to_queue(queue_name, message, ttl_seconds)
        time.sleep(5)

when I run this program the expiration is still 7 days as per in the image

found the error updated the code above

Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


I am able to send data but I am unable to custom the expiration time like to 10 seconds 1 day like that. But in azure portal able to do it. below image azure portal.

Here is the code to send message with custom time expiration of 10 seconds.
Code:
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient, QueueMessage
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
 
connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat78932;AccountKey=4HZtcQdFTVYUOxxxxxxiaXkqGxxxE+GKlDIpX4SjzQ+AStVic1FQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
       
def send_message_to_queue(queue_name, message, ttl_seconds):
        queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, queue_name)
        queue_client.send_message(content=message,time_to_live=ttl_seconds)
        print(f"Message '{message}' sent to queue '{queue_name}' with expiration in {ttl_seconds} seconds.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue_name = 'testq'
    message = "hello"
    ttl_seconds = 10  # TTL of 10 seconds
send_message_to_queue(queue_name, message, ttl_seconds)

Output:
Message 'hello' sent to queue 'testq' with expiration in 10 seconds.


Portal:

Reference:
azure.storage.queue.QueueClient class | Microsoft Learn
